# COleSafeArray vs CComSafeArray

Tags: c++, windows, com, mfc

I am in a situation where I have a COM object that I need to use in come windows only C++ code. The COM object has functions that accept SAFEARRAYs as arguments to pass arrays of bytes. After looking at the SAFEARRAY API ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221145(v=vs.85).aspx ) I decided it wasn't what I wanted  and that I should find an object oriented wrapper. I tried looking for open source ones and I didn't find any. I found that microsoft has created two objects that seem to encapsulate SAFEARRAY. It looks like the CComSafeArray is exactly what I need, and like the the COleSafeArray might be useful but could exist only for legacy compatibility.

Is COleSafeArray just around for historical compatibility or is there something I am missing?

When should COleSafeArray be used instead of CComSafeArray?

Are there any open source implementations that might be worth looking into?

What are the Pros and Cons of each?

Comment: COleSafeArray is *old*, part of MFC and written before the C++ language had templates.  CComSafeArray is part of ATL and is a template class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is obvious from class names.

MFC `COleSafeArray` is designed to support OLE Automation and is actually wrapper for OLE `VARIANT` struct (which can contain `SAFEARRAY`). It works generally with array elements as they are of `VARIANT` type so you need to select & extract appropriate type manually.

ATL `CComSafeArray` is designed to support `SAFEARRAY` for generic COM and is actually wrapper for `SAFEARRAY` struct. It's template class parametrized with array elements type.

In general you shall use `CComSafeArray`, it's easier and simplier, accessing elements almost same way as for regular arrays/vectors.

`COleSafeArray` may be preferable sometimes if you work with OLE Automation interfaces that intensively use `VARIANT` parameters, e.g. automating MS Office, using Visual Basic components etc. For comparision in this case with `CComSafeArray` you will need to wrap/unwrap it manually to/from `VARIANT` object.